# jQuery replaceWith not working in Firefox 42

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using the following code as my jQuery jumpoff point for replacing content on some sites. On every site I've ued it, this bit of jQuery has worked without problem... until now.

For some reason, my replaceWith isn't working in Firefox on this one site and I can't seem to track down the reason.

I've du around here looking for the answer and, while I've found other cases of replaceWith not working, none seem to point me in the right direction to figuring out/fixing my particualr issue.

So, below is my bit of script and, all I want to do is replace phone numbers in paragraphs and in the header top right area. Again, it's working in Chrome, Edge, and Safari but, no go in Firefox.

Oh, a link to the site I'm having the problem on:
http://greenvilledisabilitylawyer.net/

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // NUM SWAP IN DIV
    $("li.menu-item-33").replaceWith(
        "<li id='menu-item-33' class='numbertop menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-33'><a href='tel:8643004994'> Free Consultation (864) 300-4994</a></div>"
    );
    // NUM SWAP IN PARAGRAPH
    $('p').not('.site-title').each(function() {
        var num1 = $(this).text().replace(/235-0886/g,
            "300-4994");
        $(this).text(num1);
    });
    // NUM SWAP IN PARAGRAPH
    $('p').not('.site-title').each(function() {
        var num2 = $(this).text().replace(/369-7200/g,
            "210-3290");
        $(this).text(num2);
    });
});
```

Comment: Uhm, a LI element closed with `</div>` seems like really **invalid** HTML to me

Comment: It seems to be working on my version of FireFox 42.  Are you getting a console error or is the text just not appearing?

Comment: @adeneo - Yep, that closing div tag was a boo boo on my part. I've corrected that but, it's still not working.

Comment: @BrianHoover - Exactly, the text simply isn't appearing in my browser (FF42) at all. The thing is, the text appears just fine in other sites where I've done this very same bit of jQuery but, for whatever reason, not on this one. :( Scratching my head....

Comment: @AlonsoF1 Did you check the generated html in the browser?

Comment: What about this Vanilla JS alternative ? https://github.com/Haeresis/vanilla-js#replace $(".class")[0] is the original item allow you to use function as explained in link before.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is not working in your side.Can you please check the console. 
Here is a snippet that I tried with and it worked fine

JS

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // NUM SWAP IN DIV
  setTimeout(function(){
   $("li.menu-item-33").replaceWith(
        "<li id='menu-item-33' class='numbertop menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-33'><a href='tel:8643004994'> Free Consultation (864) 300-4994</a></li>");
  },5000)
});
```

**NOTE:** I used setTimeout just to trigger the change

[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qgs8pyy8/)